# PHP Script Results in Warnings of array_merge and usort. Resulting files are null

Tags: php

I am quite confused on this matter.  I have a PHP file located on my server.  It is written to pull event information from Google Calendar and write the resulting data into separate text files.  The PHP file has been working fine up until the first of July.  I am not sure what happened to result in the errors, but the same script is being used by another individual (he wrote it, and it is still working fine for him), so I am pretty sure that it isn't the result of something Google has changed.  Here is the specific errors that are returned when the file is accessed.

`Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 111

Warning: usort() [function.usort]: The argument should be an array in /home/westfork/public_html/AppData/DataSources/index.php on line 120`

Here is the PHP file.  Any help would be great.

```
<?php

$today = date("F j, Y");
$thisWeek = date("W");
$thisYear = date("Y");


/*
 *  Represents individual events within a calendar
 */
Class Event
{   
public $allDay; // "1" or ""
public $multiDay; // "1" or ""
public $date; // "F j, Y"
public $time; // String
public $start; // Timestamp
public $end; // Timestamp
public $section; // String
public $title; // String
public $description; // String
public $location; // String

/**
 * @param array $event - an entry node from the Google calendar feed
 */
public function __construct($event) 
{               
    // set the Event properties based on the array keys and values
    foreach($event as $key=>$value) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }

    $this->time = $this->relativeTime();

    // set the section header for this event
    $this->section = $this->sectionHeader();

}

/**
 * @return string - the section heading based on when the event is in relation to the 
 * current date, e.g., "Today", "This Week", "May", "Dec", etc.
 */
protected function sectionHeader() {
    global $today, $thisWeek, $thisYear;

    // determine which section header to apply
    if (strtotime($today) == $this->date) {
        return "Today";
    } else if (date("F j, Y", strtotime($today) + (60*60*24)) === date("F j, Y", $this->date)) {
        return "Tomorrow";
    } else if ($thisYear === date("Y", $this->date)) { 
        return date("l, F j", $this->date);
    } else {
        return date("l, F j, Y", $this->date);
    }
}

protected function relativeTime() {
    // if the event isn't and all-day event, set the relative start and end times
    if (!$this->allDay) {

        // if the start and end times are outside of the current day, set $allDay to "1"
        if ($this->start <= $this->date && $this->end >= $this->date + (60*60*24)) {
            return "All Day";
        }
        // if both the start and end are within the current day
        else if ($this->start > $this->date && $this->end < $this->date + (60*60*24)) {
            return date("g:i A", $this->start) . " - " . date("g:i A", $this->end);
        }

        // if the start is within the current day
        else if ($this->start > $this->date && $this->start < $this->date + (60*60*24)) {
            return date("g:i A", $this->start);
        }
        // if the end is within the current day
        else if ($this->end > $this->date && $this->end < $this->date + (60*60*24)) {
            return 'ends: ' . date("g:i A", $this->start);
        }
    } else {
        return "All Day";
    }
}


}

/*
 *  Represents a calendar containing events
 */
Class Calendar
{
protected $events = array();
protected $name;

/**
 * @param String $name - the name of the calendar (will be used as the file name for saving)
 */
public function __construct($name) 
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * Adds a an array of Event to the calendar. 
 *  @param array $events - an array of Events
 */
public function addEvents($events)
{
    $this->events = array_merge($this->events, $events);
    $this->sortEvents();
}

/**
 * Sorts the $this->events array 
 */
protected function sortEvents()
{
    usort($this->events, array($this, 'compareTwoEventsForSort'));
}

/**
 * Compare function for sortEvents()
 * Compares first by Event::$date and then Event::$start
 */
protected function compareTwoEventsForSort($x, $y) {

    // compare the dates
    if ( $x->date < $y->date) {
      return -1;
    }
    if ( $x->date > $y->date) {
        return 1;
    }

    // the dates are equal, so now compare the times
    if ($x->start < $y->start) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($x->start > $y->start) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

public function listEvents() {
    print_r($this->events);
}

public function saveCalendarAsFile() {
    // Log the results into separate calendar text files.
    $file = fopen("{$this->name}.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($file, json_encode($this->events));
    fclose($file);      
}   
}

/*
 *  Handles the creation and saving of Calendars and Events
 */
Class CalendarController
{

public $calendar;

/**
 * @param String $id - the id of the google calendar
 */
public function __construct($name, $id)
{       
    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    if ( strtotime(date("Y") . "-06-01") > time()) {
        $yearEnd = date("Y") . "-08-01";
    } else {
        $yearEnd = ((int) date("Y") + 1) . "-08-01";
    }

    $url = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{$id}/public/";
    $url .= "full?";
    $url .= "&start-min=$today&start-max=$yearEnd";
    $url .= "&max-results=1000";
    $url .= "&orderby=starttime";
    $url .= "&sortorder=a";
    $url .= "&singleevents=true";
    $url .= "&ctz=America/Chicago";
    $url .= "&fields=entry(title,content,gd:where,gd:when)";

    $xml = file_get_contents($url);

    // get rid of the namespace "gd:"
    $xml = str_replace("gd:", "", $xml);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

    $events = $this->parseEventsFromGoogleXML($xml);
    $this->calendar = new Calendar($name);
    $this->calendar->addEvents($events);
}

public function listCalendarEvents() {
    $this->calendar->listEvents();
}

public function saveCalendarAsFile() {
    $this->calendar->saveCalendarAsFile();
}

/**
 * @param SimpleXMLElement $xml - a simpleXML object of the Google calendar feed
 */
protected function parseEventsFromGoogleXML($xml)
{
    global $today;

    $events = array();
    foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {

        $start = strtotime($entry->when['startTime']);
        $end = strtotime($entry->when['endTime']);

        // if the $end time is 12:00 AM the next morning, make it 11:59 PM the previous day
        if (date("H:i", $end) === "00:00") {
            $end -= 1;
        }

        $startDate = date("F j, Y", $start);
        $endDate = date("F j, Y", $end);

        $allDay = (strpos($entry->when['startTime'] . $entry->when['endTime'], "T") === false) ? "1" : "";
        $multiDay = ($startDate !== $endDate) ? "1" : "";

        // iterate through each day of the event
        $loopEndDate = strtotime($endDate);
        $loopToday = strtotime($today);
        $loopDate = strtotime($startDate);

        for ( ; $loopDate <= $loopEndDate; $loopDate += (60*60*24) )
        {               
            if ($loopDate >= $loopToday) {

                // clean up the description text
                // replace <br> tags with \n, delete \t characters, and remove all non-link tags
                $description = (string) $entry->content;
                $description = trim($description);
                $description = preg_replace("/<br[^>]*>/i", "\n", $description);
                $description = preg_replace("/\n */", "\n", $description);
                $description = preg_replace("/\n{3,}/", "\n\n", $description);
                $description = strip_tags($description, "<a>");
                $description = preg_replace("/([ \t]*$)|(^[ \t]*)/m", "", $description);
                $description = htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);

                $event = new Event(array(
                    'date' => $loopDate,
                    'allDay' => $allDay,
                    'multiDay' => $multiDay,
                    'start' => $start,
                    'end' => $end,
                    'title' => (string) $entry->title,
                    'description' => $description,
                    'location' => (string) $entry->where['valueString'],
                ));
                $events[] = $event;
            }
        }
    }
    return $events;
}

}


$calendars = array(
"Academic" => "westmont.edu_tker7t4jgfoi6i7msien0smimk@group.calendar.google.com",
"Athletics" => "westmont.edu_a2o3k05co4i3tt5voc1ginging@group.calendar.google.com",
"Chapel" => "westmont.edu_olec4f6vb91cn02e9higcab57c@group.calendar.google.com",
"Events" => "westmont.edu_mnjvcd9e9224q9m723nurbl8ks@group.calendar.google.com",
"Dining" => "3mipcafj6qeqs1m9mfpngv97q0@group.calendar.google.com",
"Band" => "westforkband.org_kg9n1kin34c3eovt6l2gomvlb8%40group.calendar.google.com",
"Rehearsal" => "westforkband.org_mvibrgiu71ldvrnfh6r4rdf3fc@group.calendar.google.com",
"Parking" => "westforkband.org_t8jj4b5l9b3li2n31ce67ecc84@group.calendar.google.com",
// "Development" => "westmont.edu_atsog3h7vsf4k3s5r1f6e2p660%40group.calendar.google.com",

);


foreach($calendars as $name=>$id) {
$ecc = new CalendarController($name, $id);
$ecc->listCalendarEvents();
$ecc->saveCalendarAsFile();
}
```

Comment: sorry, cant reproduce. at least not on lamp 5.3.5

Comment: Please trim down your code to the bare essentials. Those hungry for points might put in the effort, those less inclined might vote to close your question. We really like simple input -> minimum code -> output. In doing so, you might even find the error yourself.

Comment: Hello Again everyone.  Sorry about this, but the reason none of the problems were able to be reproduced is because they apparently didn't exist in the code I gave you.  For some reason, any changes I made to files (including deleting) would be reflected in the web based file manager, but were not actually applied.  I had to use FTP to get any permanent file changes to take place.  I'm not sure what was going on with that, but the problem is gone.  Thanks so much for the help you all have given.  I apologize for taking up your time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried outputting what is in the `$events` parameter in the `addEvents` method?

Try doing a `var_dump($events);` before line 111 and see what's coming in. .

```
var_dump($events);
$this->events = array_merge($this->events, $events);
```

That will show you the full structure of  `$events` including the property types.  If this is running via a cron job or something, you may want to output the var to a log file or something.

Also, you will do well to check that `$events` is an array before trying to merge it:

```
if (is_array($events)) {
    $this->events = array_merge($this->events, $events);
    $this->sortEvents();
}
```

If you SHOULD be an array every time, you should still keep the condition, but add an `else` that notifies you via log of what `$events` was so you can handle it properly in those instances.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say that, but I pasted the code provided and it works for me (thanks to the given calendar addresses). `parseEventsFromGoogleXML` must fail, maybe because the connection error, or time limit, or anything. You need to handle that. Make the `$events` an empty array before `$events = $this->parseEventsFromGoogleXML($xml);`, use exceptions and try/catch them, Check connection and/or XML result before moving forward, etc. Make sure, that your server can handle the file from the outside.